# ConQAT C# clone analysis: "No factory found for element" for all C# files

Tags: c#, conqat

Using the Open Source code analysis tool [ConQAT](http://conqat.cs.tum.edu/index.php/ConQAT), I created a C# clone analysis by clicking

**`New->Run config->code_clones->CsCodeAnalysis.`**

When I run it, the report says for each C# file:

> No factory found for element myproject/myfile.cs

Is it a bug in ConQAT?

Comment: I did that already, no reply. It is Open Source, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you were using **Cs*Clone*Analysis**.

This configuration reads the solution files to determine the actual C# files that are included in the analysis. From the message I would guess that you tried to directly pass the C# files in, which does not work. As the files do not end in **.sln** you get an error.

See the ConQAT examples (clonedetection-example-nunit.cqr) for how to use this configuration.

It is also possible to directly pass C# files to a clone detection, but you would need a different configuration then.